# Setting up a Build machine with TeamCity

Tags: c#, build, teamcity

I'm currently dealing with multiple small-time dev projects at work.

I'd like to formalize the proecss and so i've installed TeamCity which was recommended by many and is also free for small projects.

I'd like to know -- which components are needed to build projects on a build agent machine ?

I'm building C# projects; do i need to install VS2010 on every build machine? only some subset of it? what exactly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing .NET and the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924) (the .NET parts) should be sufficient. Depending on the project types you are using, it will be necessary to copy build targets from your local machine to the build agents (but this is a one time configuration).

Comment: How does TeamCity compile my projects? does it use the csc.exe compiler ? This compiler is not a part of the Windows SDK, is it ?

Comment: TeamCity has different build runners. One of them is the Visual Studio Runner which uses IMHO msbuild for building the solutions. At the very end csc is used. All of these is included in the Windows SDK/.NET-Framework.

Answer (score 6):

Only the .Net framework ( which includes msbuild ) should be enough. No need, and it is probably not a good idea in most cases, to install Visual Studio on build agents. Keep the installed stuff on build agent to bare minimum needed to build.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to install the framework 4.0 you don't need the all VS2010.
Maybe it's a web project and you use the Web Deployment Pakage so you will need to install this package: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=89f2c4f5-5d3a-49b6-bcad-f776c6edfa63&displaylang=en

Hope this helps.